# HBase schema design in User Profiling

Tags: schema, hbase

I'm new to HBase and I'm trying to use it for one of our projects. The background is like this:

1. There're hundreds of mobile applications on our platform.
2. Each user has a profile: user name, IP address, email, preferences, etc.
3. Within each application, each user has some activities we want to keep track of. Examples include voice queries within s-voice, location history within foursquare and so on.

And here're some example access patterns:

1. Based on the data, we can do data mining to learn some user behavior so as to provide better answers.
2. We might want to find what happens recently for each user.
3. We might want to do some aggregates such as how many users ask "what weather it is in Seattle".

Please advise what kind of HBase table schema design I should design. Thanks a lot!!

Ad

Comment: How often do you expect to get the user info? Everytime a user uses an app?

Comment: most probably, we need to know who it is.